# Encountering an int error in python for a script walking data, how to solve it?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am having a problem with the following code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path2v1'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('train.csv'):
            combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
            
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

It is returning the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b0f594f68181> in <module>
      8             combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames])
      9 
---> 10 combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
     11 

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

It was working fine for me yesterday but for some reason today I woke up to these errors. Any ideas why this happened?

Comment: try printing the value of combined_csv(`print(combined_csv)`) right before you do `combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Comment: The error means that `combined_csv` is not a pandas dataframe.  Furthermore, you probably want to make `combined_csv` an empy dataframe, then append to it inside the loop, because you're redefining it as a new dataframe each time the file ends with train.csv

Comment: @EMiller you absolutely do not want to do this. appending to a dataframe reallocates the entire dataframe _every time_. what  they should do is store a list of dataframes and concat at  the end

Comment: @acushner, great point.  My comment was mostly meant to convey that the OP is erasing data by writing over the dataframe on subsequent iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions here, but I think you want to do something like this:

```
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) 
   for _,_,files in os.walk('path2v1') 
   for file in files if file.endswith('train.csv')])
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

per the comment from @acushner, a list of dataframes is created, THEN concatenated to make the dataframe.

Comment: Thank You for taking Time to help. I got the following error from this code:
<ipython-input-5-c04bf09eb33b> in <module>      1 combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) 
----> 2    for _,_,files in os.walk('path2v1')

Comment: 3    for file in files if file.endswith('.csv')])
      4 combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv",index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')

Comment: /opt/anaconda3/envs/PST_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    279         verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
    280         copy=copy,
--> 281         sort=sort,
    282     )
    283 
~/opt/anaconda3/envs/PST_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    327

Comment: 328         if len(objs) == 0:
--> 329             raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")
    330 
    331         if keys is None:
ValueError: No objects to concatenate

Comment: likely, there are no objects to concatenate because you are not finding any files.  Try this:
```
files = [file for _,_,files in os.walk('path2v1') 
   for file in files if file.endswith('train.csv')]
```
are there entries in the ```files``` list?